# Como realizo esta consulta en sql

Tags: mysql, sql

he estado dandole vueltas ya que e quedado en un punto muerto con esta consulta
Dejo unas imagenes para que se entienda como esta formada la base de datos
[image: Esa seria como están relacionadas las tablas entre si]

Esa seria como están relacionadas las tablas entre si

[image: Tabla syu con datos]

Tabla syu con sus respectivos datos de las claves foraneas

[image: Tabla salas con datos]

Esta es la tabla salas y sus datos

[image: Tabla usuarios con datos]

Y finalmente tabla usuarios con datos

Mi base de datos es de un gran edificio enfocado a los juegos de mesa y recreativos, en los cuales se pueden inscribir cada usuarios, en la tabla sala tambien habra salas privadas, en las que solo estaran javi, juan y luis por ejemplo, como  se muestra en la base de datos syu, la cuestion es que me gustaria saber como debo hacer la consulta para encontrar solo a los usuarios javi, juan y luis sin poner el idc, ya que estos pueden tener varias salas privadas para ellos 3,

He intentado hacer la consulta de la siguiente forma

```
Select salas.nombreSala from salas 
WHERE salas.idc=(Select syu.idc from syu 
where syu.nombre="javi" and syu.nombre="juan" and syu.nombre="luis")
```

El problema es que me sale en blanco, despues de pensarlo e entendido el porque, pero no se me ocurre ninguna forma de como realizar dicha consulta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay un problema con el uso de los operadores lógicos en

```
where syu.nombre="javi" and syu.nombre="juan" and syu.nombre="luis")
```

Porque nunca se dará el caso de que en syu.nombre tengas, al mismo tiempo, en el mismo registro, los valores "javi", "juan" y "luis"

**Lo que sí podrías hacer es algo similar:**

```
Select salas.nombreSala from salas 
WHERE salas.idc IN (Select syu.idc from syu 
where syu.nombre="javi" OR syu.nombre="juan" OR syu.nombre="luis");
```

***Nótese el uso de [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) en lugar de "=", que pedirá pertenencia a un conjunto, y de `OR` en lugar de `AND`, para incluir *cualquiera* de los valores.***

## EDICION

Por los comentarios del autor de la pregunta:

> "salas en las que los únicos tres usuarios sean JAVI, JUAN y LUIS"
>   (que, de acuerdo a los datos de ejemplo, sería la sala mc1)

Para eso vamos a hacer 4 joins de la tabla `salas` con la tabla `syu`.

- La primera vez, pidiendo registros en los que exista el usuario "javi".
- La segunda, pidiendo que exista el usuario "juan".
- La tercera, que exista el usuario "luis".
- La cuarta, pidiendo usuarios que no sean "javi" ni "juan" ni "luis".

En el `WHERE` es donde refinamos la búsqueda:

- pedimos que en el primer `join` se hayan traído registros (sí o sí que
  esté "javi");
- que en el segundo sí o sí esté "juan";
- que en el tercero sí o sí esté "luis";
- y que en el cuarto NO HAYA REGISTROS (es decir *"que sólo estén ellos tres"*)

```
SELECT salas.nombreSala FROM salas
LEFT JOIN syu syu1 ON salas.idc=syu1.idc and syu1.nombre="javi"
LEFT JOIN syu syu2 ON salas.idc=syu2.idc and syu2.nombre="juan"
LEFT JOIN syu syu3 ON salas.idc=syu3.idc and syu3.nombre="luis"
LEFT JOIN syu syu4 ON salas.idc=syu4.idc and syu4.nombre NOT IN ("javi","juan","luis")
WHERE syu1.nombre IS NOT NULL
AND syu2.nombre IS NOT NULL
AND syu3.nombre IS NOT NULL
AND syu4.nombre IS NULL;
```

Comment: Despues de hacer la consulta entendí el porque no se podía hacer con and, tu consulta esta bien si quieres sacar las salas en donde esten esos usuarios registrados aunque falte uno de ellos, yo necesito saber en que salas estan solo ellos 3 y nadie mas registrados, quiza podría cambiar la forma en la que esta montada mi base de datos, pero realmente esta es la mejor forma

Comment: O sea "salas en las que los únicos tres usuarios sean JAVI, JUAN y LUIS" ? (que, de acuerdo a tus datos de ejemplo, sería la sala mc1)

Comment: Exactamente asi seria, tambien me podeis sugerir cambiar la estructura de mi base de datos, pero lo que e dicho antes, yo creo que asi es la mejor forma

Comment: gracias buena explicacion y funciona perfectamente, era justo lo que queria que hiciera, mi conocimiento de sql es algo basico